# Types in Python - Google Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Getting a bit peeved now;

I have a model and a class thats just storing a get request in the database; basic tracking.

```
class SearchRec(db.Model):
  WebSite = db.StringProperty()#required=True
  WebPage = db.StringProperty()
  CountryNM = db.StringProperty()
  PrefMailing = db.BooleanProperty()
  DateStamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  IP = db.StringProperty()

class AddSearch(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    searchRec = SearchRec()

    searchRec.WebSite = self.request.get('WEBSITE')
    searchRec.WebPage = self.request.get('WEBPAGE')
    searchRec.CountryNM = self.request.get('COUNTRY')
    searchRec.PrefMailing = bool(self.request.get('MAIL'))
    searchRec.IP = self.request.get('IP')
```

Bool has my biscuit; I thought that setting bool(self.reque....) would set the type of the string but no matter what I pass it it still stores it as TRUE in the database.
I had the same issue with using required=True on strings for the model; the damn thing kept saying that nothing was being passed... but it had.

Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added a lot of layers of complication to understanding what the bool() build-in function does. Why don't you test it out directly on the command-line, before embedding it deep in your google app engine code.

What you'd discover is that the bool() function uses python's truth values:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

> The following values are considered
>   false:
>
> ```
> * None
> * False
> * zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> * any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> * any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> * instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
>    `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer
>    zero or bool value False. [1]
> ```
>
> All other values are considered true —
>   so objects of many types are always
>   true.

In particular - any non-empty string is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

> Bool has my biscuit; I thought that setting bool(self.reque....) would set the type of the string but no matter what I pass it it still stores it as TRUE in the database.

Well, what's the value of `self.request.get('MAIL')`?  If it's anything other than an empty string or `None`, `bool` will see it as `True`.

> I had the same issue with using required=True on strings for the model; the damn thing kept saying that nothing was being passed... but it had.

If you set a property to `required=True`, then you *must* pass it to the model's constructor.  So, if `WebSite` is a required property, you need to construct your `searchRec` like so:

```
searchRec = SearchRec(WebSite=self.request.get('WEBSITE'))
```

Comment: Mail was set to False. Thanks for answering the second bit :o)

Comment: Was it set to False, or 'False'? One is a boolean, the other is a string - and self.request.get only returns strings (or None).

Comment: It was set to False via self.request.get so I expect it was string; I falsely assumed that sticking bool() around it was the equivalent of changing the type. I have to say I preffer my languages with curly brackets and line ending semi-colons. This feels like a more anal version of VB... but its fast which is the big draw (Appengine java is awful)